# Is there any way to optimize / collect Apache upstream connections?

Tags: apache2

We have an apache performance issue. This occurs only if too many TCP connections is opened to the next server. Everything is fine if the number of tcp connections is low.
Is there any way to limit/collect these?

I don't want to limit the clients from the internet(I know how to do that) but limit the connections what apache opens to forward requests to the next server (inside).

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to limit upstream connections? What is the actual performance issue? The way you have written this question indicates an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: I do jmeter performance tests using rest api calls throught the apache to the frontend server. I do this with 50,150,300 tcp connections. The backend (API load) is the same but the number of connections differs. The response times are OK with 50, acceptable with 150 but very slow with 300.

Comment: It doesn't follow that Apache is making too many connections to the backend. The usual reason for this is that the application is busy or has some sort of resource contention. Look there first.

Comment: The app is very fast if I test it through tomcat without Apache.

Comment: Even with 300 connections? OK, then maybe you're on to something. Though it doesn't make sense why, if Apache is slow, you want to slow it down even more?

Comment: Nginx can do this I just want to achieve the same thing.
https://cdn-1.wp.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Slide-14-Load-Balancing.png
Otherwise the problem is on Apache mod_proxy (it has high self response time on the monitoring tool)